# Lightroom, same keyword multiple places in the hierarchy?

Tags: lightroom, keywords

Is there any way to have the same keyword as a sub-keyword under multiple parent keywords?

I count many of my colleagues as friends, and I'd like to tag the photos with a keyword for their name, so I would like this structure:

- People

  - Colleagues

    - Company Name

      - Friend 1
  - Friends

    - Friend 1

It seems my only option is to create two tags for my friend, ie.

- People

  - Colleagues

    - Company Name

      - Friend 1 @ Company Name
  - Friends

    - Friend 1

is there no other option? Basically I would to have it so that if I tag a photo as "Friend 1", it will show both if I search for the keyword "Friends" and for the keyword "Colleagues".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest structuring your keywords differently. You're mixing up a few definition concepts together, which is why the hierarchy is getting confused.

One of the items a person has is their identity. Another is their relationsihp with you. It'll be less confusing if you build those hierarchies separately:

People
   Names
      Fred Forsythe
      Sarah Jones
      Jonathan Appleby
   Relationship
      co-worker @ IBM
      co-worker @ Palm
      friend
      member of church
      scout troop
      Niece
      Grandfather

So when they're in a picture, you tag them with their name, and then tag them with the item(s) that define their relationship with you at the time the picture was taken. That may well change over time, especially with co-workers.

The definition of that person in that picture then is the set of keywords attached to the picture, rather than trying to create a single keyword that might be replicated to cover multiple situations into a single keyword. keyword sets become really powerful in defining a picture as you figure out how best to build the structures.

I've written in detail how I've built my keyword system, and a number of people have told me it's been quite helpful as they've been defining out their own.

http://www.chuqui.com/thoughts-on-lightroom-keywords/

(it'll be revised later this year, since I've started using synonyms a lot more extensively than I document in that piece. They're another way to handle this kind of situation in some of the situations, because you can attach those secondary characteristics to the main keyword and they get attached automatically. The downside is that if the relationships change and you edit the keyword (a co-worker changes jobs), that change is propogated to all photos, not just future ones, so the moment-in-time aspect of assigning keywords gets lost. but for keyword relationships that don't change (like, oh, "mom"), it can simplify assignment.

Answer (score 0):

Keywords don't really have a 'hierarchy' like what you're describing. If you tag friend-1 with 'friend, colleague', and friend-2 with 'friend', both would should up when applying a library filter > text > keywords > contain all > 'friend'. However only friend-1 would show up if you searched 'colleague'.

I hope that helps.